# Rails: nested model: how to get children's new records which are just created in the parent's controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My nested models are like:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

and in the parent controller "Album", after saved/updated the parent object @album with nested attributes of photos in params, I want to get the children's records (ids or objects) which are just created/updated altogether with parent because I'll need them in the view.

My current Album's controller looks like:

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
  @album = Album.new(album_params)
  @album.save
  @photo = @album.photos.last

  format.html
  format.js
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  @album.update_attributes(album_params)
  @photo = @album.photos.last

  format.html
  format.js
  end
end
```

With this (@album.photos.last), I can get only the last one record of Photos that is saved with the parent, supposing that the last one is the one created by saving one step before in the create action. But it won't be good in the update action... And what I really want to achieve is to get the photos' records which their data was present in params as photos_attributes, and pass them to @photos (plural).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are the photos being created as they should? If so, `@photos = @album.photos` should work if the relationship is present. You'll need to loop through them to display them, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only the photos that were updated during the process, you can do the following:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    already_existing_photo_ids = @album.photos.pluck(:id)
    @album.update_attributes(album_params)
    @photos = @album.photos.where('id NOT IN (?)', already_existing_photo_ids)

    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

And for the create action, just use all the photos associated with the album:

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    @album = Album.new(album_params)
    @album.save
    @photos = @album.photos

    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then you can loop on the `@photos` to display each of the photos created/updated

Comment: Thanks @MrYoshiji.

"But this will not select photos that were created during an update of the album record", I see. And thinking if there is a way to hook the result from the SQL query like this:

`INSERT INTO "photos" ("img_name", "img_uid", "author", "attachable_type", "attachable_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["img_name", "abc.jpg"], ["img_uid", "2016/03/15/x.jpg"], ["author", ""], ["attachable_type", "Album"], ["attachable_id", 46], ["created_at", "2016-03-15 x"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-15 x"]]`

Do you have any idea? (please ignore the polymorphic part)

Comment: You could find back the photos created with the params you used to create them. I can add this to my answer if you need it

Comment: In this case I can use "img_uid" that will be unique, but I'd like to know other ways to snatch all the saved and updated records right after saving / updating, or at least just the created records in the update action... It'll be useful also in other model's controller which doesn't have such a unique value in params...

Comment: I updated my answer with a very simple solution : retrieve the already existing photos before the update, then get all photos that were not there before the update. It should work with any kind of object and does not rely on the params, which is way better than my first suggestion.

Comment: That's great :> So, I can get both created and updated records in the update action by doing like this:
    
`updated_photo_ids = album_params[:photos_attributes].map { |_, photo_attrs| photo_attrs[:id] }.compact`
 - 
`already_existing_photo_ids = @album.photos.pluck(:id)`
 - 
`@updated_photos = @album.photos.where(id: updated_photo_ids)`
 - 
`@created_photos = @album.photos.where('id NOT IN (?)', already_existing_photo_ids)`
    
Is that alright?

Comment: Yeah you can do as you posted in your comment to separate created and updated photos.